# Syntax error with a if / else statement (Python / Selenium)

Tags: selenium, python

I'my trying to apply an if / else statement in Python to know if I have an element or not and if it is the case, click on it. But I don't know why I have a syntax error and I don't see where I have made a mistake.

This is the part of my code concerned by this issue:

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]"):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]".click()
        print "Oh this conversation already exists !"
    else:
        print "No conflict!
```

When I launch my script, I have the following syntax error:

```
>  File "group_discussion_script.py", line 51    print "Oh this
> conversation already exists !
>        ^ syntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I wonder if this line is really tolerated?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]".click()
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, I have simply forgot to close the parenthesis:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]").click()
                                                                     HERE^
```

Comment: It is better to use relative xpath expression than absolute xpath expression.